# Lucene index gets broken segments after every restart of liferay-tomcat

Tags: unix, tomcat, lucene, liferay

I have a corrupted Lucene index.  If I run "CheckIndex -fix" the problem is resolved, but as soon as I restart tomcat it becomes corrupted again.

The index directory is shared between two application servers running Liferay-Tomcat. I am fixing the index on 1 server and restarting that whilst the other is running.  This is a production environment so I cannot bring them both down.

Any suggestions please?

Before fix, CheckIndex says:

```
Opening index @ /usr/local/tomcat/liferay/lucene/0

Segments file=segments_5yk numSegments=1 version=FORMAT_SINGLE_NORM_FILE [Lucene 2.2]
  1 of 1: name=_2vg docCount=31
    compound=false
    hasProx=true
    numFiles=8
    size (MB)=0.016
    no deletions
    test: open reader.........FAILED
    WARNING: fixIndex() would remove reference to this segment; full exception:
java.io.IOException: read past EOF
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.refill(BufferedIndexInput.java:151)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedIndexInput.readByte(BufferedIndexInput.java:38)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.IndexInput.readVInt(IndexInput.java:78)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInfos.read(FieldInfos.java:335)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FieldInfos.<init>(FieldInfos.java:71)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader$CoreReaders.<init>(SegmentReader.java:119)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.get(SegmentReader.java:652)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.get(SegmentReader.java:605)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.checkIndex(CheckIndex.java:491)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex.main(CheckIndex.java:903)

WARNING: 1 broken segments (containing 31 documents) detected
WARNING: would write new segments file, and 31 documents would be lost, if -fix were specified
```

Answer (score 0):

If you access your search index with more than one application server, I would suggest integrating a Solr Server. So you don't have the problem that 2 app servers are trying to write on the same file. This could be error prone as you already found out. 
To get Solr up and running you have to follow those steps:

- Install a Solr Server on any machine you like. A machine running only Solr would be quite preferable.
- Install the Solr search portlet in Liferay
- Adjust the config files according to the setup document of Sol Search portlet.

Here are some additional links:

http://www.liferay.com/de/marketplace/-/mp/application/15193648

http://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Pluggable+Enterprise+Search+with+Solr

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying.  It doesn't look to me like this works with Liferay 5.1 (agree?).  Yes we should upgrade, but that's a different story!  Any other ideas?

Comment: I think Solr will work with Liferay 5.1. But I think you are limited to Solr 1.3